# How can I "mount" a proxy_passed WSGI application onto a subdirectory of a website on NGINX?

Tags: nginx, web, wsgi

I am using NGINX version 1.18.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS on WSL2 version 1.2.5.0 on Windows 10

I have been trying to get to know deploying a WSGI application. I built a small thread-messaging web application I called "Fibers" with flask and wanted to try to serve it on my local network with Gunicorn behind a NginX reverse proxy. I tried to build the configuration file so that I would "mount" the fibers-application to a specific sub-path on an existing website that I previously built. So that everything matching "localhost/fibers/", would match to the fibers-application, and everything else would match against the normal site like "localhost/". Both of the sites work nicely when configured to be served as the root "/" location on nginx.conf. However I cannot get the configuration to work as described.

This is the latest nginx.conf file that I tried.

```
user www-data www-data;

http {

    include mime.types;

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            root /path_to_website/src;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            index index.py index.html;
        }

        location /fibers/ {
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/fiberrunner/Fibers/src/fibers.sock;
        }

    }
}

events {}
```

I get the website to respond on "/" normally, but the web-application on "/fibers" subdirectory is giving me a 404 not found.

I have tried going through articles, videos and stackoverflow posts and cannot find an answer or a clue what is going on. Also there is nothing else than my nginx restart messages on `/var/log/nginx/error.log`. I searched through NGINX documentation and getting started but helped puckall and have been quite hostile about learning their technology.

Both of the sites are in working order by themselves when configured under root "/".

I was expecting for the fibers-application to be accessible on the sub directory "/fibers/", and the site being accessible on root "/".

I tried switching their locations around, tried simpler subdirectory names, tried different combinations of slashes on the location endpoint, tried it with an equals siqn like `location = /fibers/`. Here some examples:

```
location /fibers/
location /fibers
location = /fibers/
location = /fibers
```

Tried also matching it with different url's on the browser side. But everytime the root website works but subdirectory app doesn't.

But as soon as I set the fibers app as root

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/fiberrunner/Fibers/src/fibers.sock;
}
```

..it starts working.

What am I not getting? Shoudn't the longest matching location get picked and then send the leftover $URI after the matched prefix get set to the proxy_pass?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to my own question with the tremendous help of David Lukeš. He made a very detailed and exhaustive article here https://dlukes.github.io/flask-wsgi-url-prefix.html.

In short: if you have formed every internal link with url_for(), you can set an environment variable SCRIPT_NAME=/url_prefix for gunicorn, and gunicorn will strip this from the start of the path of every incoming request, and add it in front of every internal link.

You can add a file containing environment variables on linux in the unit-file of the gunicorn-service you are creating if your system uses systemd as init/PID1 process. In the /etc/systemd/system/.service file under the [service] section you can set the "EnvironmentFile" variable to the path of the environment variable file you created that contains the "SCRIPT_NAME" variable. So your unit file looks something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve Flask app
After=network.target

[Service]
User=username
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/username/Project/src
**EnvironmentFile=/home/username/Project/gunicorn_env_vars**
ExecStart=/home/username/Project/.venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:project.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and environment variable file (here "gunicorn_env_vars") something like this:

```
PATH=/home/fiberrunner/poista/fiber_test/Fibers/.venv/fiber_venv/bin
**SCRIPT_NAME=/fibers**
```

Hope this helps someone else too